# NetworkX unicode problem. "&" becomes "&#38;"

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory, networkx

Hi I'm using networkX on colab to convert JSON to GML. The problem is that networkX keeps changing the "&" in JSON into "&" as below:

```
for node in data['nodes']['organisations']:
  id = node['key']
  name = node['name']
  graph.add_node(id, type='Organisation', name=name)
```

Original JSON:

```
{"node":
  {"organisations":[{"name": "College of William & Mary"}]}
}
```

Converted GML:

```
graph[node[
  id 67
  type "Organisation"
  name "College of William &#38; Mary"
]]
```

Things I tried but did not work:

1. I import html and use html.unescape().

   `name = html.unescape(node['name'])`
2. I use encode().decode('utf-8').

   `name = node['name'].encode().decode('utf-8')`

If someone knows how to fix this, please help me, thank you!!

Comment: `&` has special meaning in GML, it needs to be encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how GML works. GML encodes non-ASCII characters as HTML character entities, and since `&` begins an HTML character entity, it also needs to encode the `&` character itself as an HTML character entity. You're seeing the result of that.

If you managed to turn off this escaping somehow, you'd just be corrupting your GML.

Comment: So I can't do anything about it?

Comment: @mauralxy: Why do you *want* to do something about it? You *can* do something about it, if you would prefer to have invalid and unparseable GML, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Because I need to show the name as a label on the graph and if it's "William &#38; Mary", that will be quite ugly.

Comment: @mauralxy: If you read your GML with a proper GML parser, like `networkx.read_gml`, it should parse the HTML entities automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to change that outside GML.